# why is this json.decoder.JSONDecodeError not caught

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a load of jsonfiles with python3.5 and many of these do not have certain elements which is expected. The error/excpetion json.decoder.JSONDecodeError is absolutely expected. However I am trying to react to it but the Error is not caught somehow:

Code

```
    #/usr/bin/python3

import pymongo
import pprint
import json
import sys

jsonfile = open(sys.argv[1],'r').read()
json1 = json.loads(jsonfile)


try:
        for key1 in json1["result"]["malware"].keys():
                print("Malware: " + json1["result"]["malware"][key1]["malware"])
                print("File: " + json1["result"]["malware"][key1]["file"])
except AttributeError:
        print("We'll handle that")
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        print("We'll handle that too")
```

Still I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyjson.py", line 9, in <module>
    json1 = json.loads(jsonfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

... appreciate any help

Comment: Because it is the `json.loads()` call that throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json1 = json.loads(jsonfile)` line raises the `JSONDecodeError` exception, but that line is not in a `try` block.

You can see that it is that line that is raising the exception in the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyjson.py", line 9, in <module>
    json1 = json.loads(jsonfile)
  # ...
```

Protect `json.loads()`, either by giving it its own `try...except`:

```
try:
    json1 = json.loads(jsonfile)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("We'll handle that")
else:
    try:
        for key1 in json1["result"]["malware"].keys():
            print("Malware: " + json1["result"]["malware"][key1]["malware"])
            print("File: " + json1["result"]["malware"][key1]["file"])
    except AttributeError:
        print("We'll handle that too")
```

or by putting the line inside the `try` that surrounds the `for` loop:

```
try:
    json1 = json.loads(jsonfile)
    for key1 in json1["result"]["malware"].keys():
        print("Malware: " + json1["result"]["malware"][key1]["malware"])
        print("File: " + json1["result"]["malware"][key1]["file"])
except AttributeError:
    print("We'll handle that")
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("We'll handle that too")
```

Note that the *item access* (subscription) can throw a `KeyError`, `IndexError` or `TypeError` exception, depending on the type of object that `[...]` is applied, and you do not need to use `.keys()` to iterate over the keys of a dictionary. Next, since you are only interested in the dictionary *values*, you should really iterate over `.values()` to make the code more readable.

The following would be a more complete way to handle bad JSON data:

```
try:
    data = json.loads(jsonfile)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("Malformed JSON data, can't decode", e)
else:
    try:
        for entry in data["result"]["malware"].values():
            print("Malware:", entry["malware"])
            print("File:", entry["file"])
    except (AttributeError, IndexError, TypeError, KeyError) as e
        print("Unexpected data structure from the JSON file", e)
```

Comment: Well I really earned these minus points there. However, thanks alot for pointing this out!